# Azure data disk for Parse Server

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, parse-server

I  already have deployed an Ubuntu VM from Azure and I want to install Parse Server on it. Yesterday, I saw this:
[screenshot from azure docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spMlW.png)

This is what I have on "Disks" of my server now:
[screenshot from azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcLQ7.png)

My question is whether I need to add a new data disk to install Parse Server, or can I do it having the OS disk only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether I need to add a new data disk to install Parse
>   Server, or can I do it having the OS disk only?

We'd better add a new data disk to host application or data.

By default, Linux VM OS disk size is 30 GB, maximum capacity of 2048 GB.

If you just want to create a test lab, I think you can host your application or data on OS disk.

If not a test lab, I think we should create a new disk to host Application or data. Each data disk has a maximum capacity of 4095 GB, add new data disk, we can have more **IO**.

You add extra disks as needed per your space and IOps requirements. Each disk has a performance target of 500 IOps for Standard Storage and up to 5000 IOps per disk for Premium Storage.

More information about Azure VM IOps, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/andrewc/2016/09/09/understanding-azure-virtual-machine-iops-throughput-and-disk-latency/).

Also if you want to add a new data disk, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal).

Comment: Hello @Jason and thanks for your answer! This is a screenshot of my system: https://prnt.sc/gwfw8w As I understand, the /dev/sda1 disk, is the OS disk, which is mounted under root. Could you tell me what the /dev/sdb1 disk is?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras  that is temporary disk, not used for store data, it is a SSD disk, when we restart VM, we will lost data in that disk.

Comment: Ok! Last thing... Could you tell me how much does a premium data disk of e.g. 50 GB cost?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras premium disk 50GB, p10 price, about $19.7/month,

Comment: Last-last thing... In order to install Parser Server, you need to install some other things, like python-software-properties package, nodejs etc (except mongodb). Is it ok for those stuff to be installed to the OS disk? They got automatically installed there!

Comment: @SotirisKaniras it is ok, they will not create more data there:)